# Creating nested object for a following Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested-loops

I want to build an object similar to following the structure:

```
record 1 {id,name,desc}
   record 2 {id,name,desc}
        record 3 {id,name,desc}
            record 4 {id,name,desc}
```

Its a nested structure where the record 1 is the parent and the record 2 is the child of record 1, record 3 is the child of record 2, and so on.

I have gone through various posts in stack overflow, which suggests using methods like push, put etc which I am unable to generate correctly. Please help.

Goal

```
{
    "8b9e235c0fe412004e938fbce1050e0f": [
        {
            "name": "Parent 1",
            "childs": [
                "caf23c95db3110100cc4bd513996195d": {
                    "name": "Child of Parent 1"
                    "childs": [
                                   "caf23c95db3110100cc4bd513996195d": {
                                    "name": "Child of Child 2"
                                    }
                              ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure if its the right order way but the idea is to turn the following object into a nested one:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Level 2",
    "childId": "caf23c95db3110100cc4bd513996195d",
    "parentId": "8b9e235c0fe412004e938fbce1050e0f",
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 3",
    "childId": "c303f495db3110100cc4bd51399619b8",
    "parentId": "caf23c95db3110100cc4bd513996195d",
    "description": null,
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 4",
    "childId": "be133895db3110100cc4bd51399619ba",
    "parentId": "c303f495db3110100cc4bd51399619b8",
    "description": null,
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Intrusion and Incident Response Standard Operating Procedure",
    "id": "8b9e235c0fe412004e938fbce1050e0f",
    "description": "blablalblablabab",
    "level": 0
  }
]
```

Using this code..

```js
function hasChild(parent,level){
var grProcessChild = new GlideRecord('sn_compliance_policy');
grProcessChild.addQuery('parent', parent);
grProcessChild.query();
while(grProcessChild.next()){
    var level = parseInt(level) + 1;
  var child =  {}; // object
  child.name = grProcessChild.getValue('name');
  child.childId = grProcessChild.getUniqueValue();
  child.parentId = grProcessChild.getValue('parent');
  child.description = grProcessChild.getValue('description');
  child.level = level;
  arrData.push(child);
  hasChild(grProcessChild.getUniqueValue(),level);
    }
}
var arrData = []; // array
var grProcess = new GlideRecord('sn_compliance_policy');
grProcess.addQuery('sys_id','8b9e235c0fe412004e938fbce1050e0f');
grProcess.query();
while(grProcess.next()){
  var root = {}; // object
  root.name = grProcess.getValue('name');
  root.id = grProcess.getUniqueValue();
  root.description = grProcess.getValue('description');
  root.level = 0; 
  hasChild(grProcess.getUniqueValue(),root.level);
  arrData.push(root);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **lodash** [`Lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduceRight) in that **_.reduceRight** method will be helpful.
Here is a [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/L31thwpo/2/) proving that it's working.